# Is it "Gaming & Chill" or "Game & Chill"

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Gday,

I came across about these products
[Gaming & Chill Hoodie](https://www.spreadshirt.net/shop/design/gaming+and+chill+video+game+controller+mens+premium+zip+hoodie-D5b16e4ebc8056369db3a11a8?sellable=GBMYywm8mkIEOa89vAl2-93-29) & [Gaming & Chill Cap](https://www.emp-online.com/p/gaming-%26-chill/440852.html).

Is *Gaming & Chill* grammatically correct? Should it not be *Game & Chill* or is it a brand name?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's possibly a reference to the expression "Netflix & chill", but replacing *Netflix* with the gerund *gaming*.

The important thing to realise is that *gaming*, as the gerund form, is acting as a noun. However, that still raises the question of grammar, as the items connected by an *and* should be of the same sort, and most likely you would read this as *chill* being a verb. The two still wouldn't agree, because even if we read *gaming* as a participle, you would still expect the items in the list to agree more closely, absent good reason from wider context to do otherwise.

There's two reasons that this may be different. The first is that *chill* is also used casually as a noun, for the characteristic of "being chilled out". It can be used as a verb, a noun, and an adjective.

The second is that this is a slogan, and not a full sentence. Applying grammar to such things will just drive you insane.

Comment: And of course, "Gaming & Chill" has the same number of syllables and pattern of stress as "Netflix & Chill", making it more likely that people will get the joke.